# In Godot shader how to use `hint` with a default value?

Tags: shader, godot4

In this documentation: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/shader_reference/shading_language.html#uniforms I see several examples of how to use `hint` but I don't know how to set a **default value** when I use a `hint`

I have tried:

```
uniform float mask_scale = 1.0 : hint_range(0.1, 10.0);
```

But I got error:

> Expected expression, found 'HINT_RANGE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uniform float mask_scale : hint_range(0.1, 10.0) = 1.0;
```